# WP7 - Control Template - unknown exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm working through a beginners book to wp7 and in one of the basic tutorials I have been encountering an unknown exception.

The control template defined in the Application resources (App.xaml) file is as below.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="Images\image.png" Width="200" Height="300" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then when I create a button that uses this template eg

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Button x:Name="CustomButton" Width="250" Height="350" Content="Custom Button" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" />
        </Grid>
```

I always get a unknown exception raised. I've narrowed it down to the

```
Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
```

Attribute in the control template but, why is there an exception? I have the content there, its in a string format. I don't know what else it may be?
When I create a project I target Windows Phone 7.1. Was there some change I'm unaware of?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
Joe

Comment: Do you have any more errordetails? Any exception message or inner exceptions? I can't reproduce the error, neither in WPF nor in Silverlight 4.

Comment: All I can add is that the exception thrown is form this method `// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
        private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }` and that the 'e' Message = "Unspecified error "

Comment: I also wonder if the windows version has something to do with it. The example works with AppPlatformVersion="7.0" but seems to throw this exception with AppPlatformVersion="7.1"
Is anyone able to shed some light on it? Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1):

Change `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextAlignment="Center" />`  to `<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />`

```
           <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Width="200"
                                   Height="300"
                                   Source="Images\image.png" />
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

[Some details about ContentControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334411%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok that worked, but do you know why the code has changed? I got this example out of a book so I believe the code was valid at some stage?

Comment: According to a stack trace in exception there where some problems with a content size. Unfortunately I can't suggest what's was wrong.

Comment: AH Ha! I fixed the issue. The problem is that the CotrolTemplate Element needed a property of **TargetType="Button"** the example had the target type in the <Style> Tag. so to fix this error for anyone else include this

`<Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">`

Comment: Nice! I missed the TagretType.